# Run some set of instructions within a time interval

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I need to generate sine wave data (only positive values) between 0 and the specified interval and for each value of the sine wave, data call some function.

Currently, I am generating sine wave data between 0 and the specified interval using below code

```
np.sin(np.linspace(0,180, count)* np.pi / 180. )
```

it generates values between 0 to 180. The size of the array is equal to count.

Now I need to call some function for each value of the generated array. The total time to call the function for each value should complete within some predefined time interval. I tried to use `sleep` function by dividing predefined time interval by `count`.

I am wondering if there is any other way to achieve the above functionality because the instruction execution can take some time.

Comment: The second part of your problem is unclear. How is `sleep()` related to everything you said before?

Comment: Like after every instruction I call `sleep` for some milliseconds so that all instructions run in equal intervals.

Comment: for eg: if there are 20 values and total time is 100 milliseconds, then `sleep` will be called with `5` milliseconds.

Comment: Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa I don't think `sleep` works the way you are thinking it does.

Comment: why do you care about limiting execution time for individual elements?  does it matter if one takes 80ms and the rest take 1ms?  what happens to the result if one takes too long?

Comment: @SamMason you are right, but I want to execute all instructions within the specified interval but not before the time interval. The instruction execution should not finish within 100 milliseconds while the mentioned interval is 10 seconds.

Comment: @SamMason all instructions change the same variable in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to run function `foo()` every 10 seconds, but the actual running time of `foo()` is unknown. The best you can do, without resorting to hard real-time programming, is to get the current time before and after the call to `foo()` and then `sleep()` for the rest of the interval:

```
import time
INTERVAL = 10 # seconds

# Repeat this fragment as needed
start = time.time() # in seconds
foo()
elapsed = time.time() - start
remains = INTERVAL - elapsed
time.sleep(remains)
```

However, keep in mind that `sleep` sleeps *at least* that much time. It may sleep longer, due to scheduling, in which case your function `foo` may be executed less frequently than needed.

Comment: Thanks that does make sense.

Comment: You mean if the process scheduling didn't start sleep right away it may take some time??

Comment: I mean the sleep return not earlier that your process is scheduled, which, in the case of non-real-time scheduler, is not under your control.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa in this example foo() will be executing operations over every item of an np array, what if the foo's total time of execution is over INTERVAL?  That work fr you as well?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Total extra time less than 100 milliseconds is acceptable.

Comment: Can I use `wait` instead of `sleep`?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda You are right, I added a provision for that case.

Comment: A non-RT scheduler does not provide any guarantee whatsoever whether the extra time is going to be 100ms or 1s or w/e. And no, `wait` is doing something totally different.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have a nice day ahead :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for putting some Python around @DYZ's answer, you could use a decorator or a context manager in order to "patch" your target function and make it take the time you want to complete.

In the following code, you have a list with five elements and you want to print each one, the total time is 5s, so print each element should take 1s.

```
import time

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Decorator.
def patch_execution_time(limit):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            init = time.time()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time.time()
            elapsed = end - init
            if elapsed < limit:
                time.sleep(limit - elapsed)
            return result
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

# Context manager, more usefull if the total time interval
# is dynamic.
class patch_execution_time_cxt(object):

    def __init__(self, operation, time):
        self.operation = operation
        self.time = time

    def __enter__(self):
        return patch_execution_time(self.time)(self.operation)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass


# Two sample functions one decarated and the other for
# ilustrating the use of the context manager.
@patch_execution_time(1)
def foo(item):
    print(item)

def foo_1(item):
    print(item)

print("Using decoreted ...")
for item in data:
    foo(item)

print("Using context manager ...")
with patch_execution_time_cxt(foo_1, 1) as patched_foo:
    for item in data:
        patched_foo(item)
```